# Redirect website after 5 seconds and match path

Tags: html, redirect

How to create a HTML redirect after 5 secconds and match same path

Example:

Redirect: www.oldsite.com/post123 to www.newsite/post123

i have tried this code but it only redirects to my home page

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=http://www.somewhere.com/" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Redirecting in 3 seconds...</h1>
</body>
```

right now im using an htaacess to do that with is

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*bberryblog.com$
RewriteRule ^$ http://unionmovil.com/category/blackberry [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(www).unionmovil.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.unionmovil.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

but i want to perform that via html so it will be after 5 secconds the redirect

Comment: Are you using javascript as well

Comment: You are probably going to need a scripting language for this.

Comment: do you know the scripting code for that ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using javascript you can write a function like:

```
var myVar=setInterval(function () {myTimer()}, 3000);

function myTimer() {
    window.location="www.newsite/post123"
}
```

Here with the set interval function you tell it to run a function every given seconds, which we set to 3 Seconds (3000). Then we direct the window to a new location within the function

Comment: Hi, but how can i make to redirect to /post123 and so on like /post456, i have 4,000 articles, and i need to redirect all of them, tnx !

Comment: YOu would probably have to write a javascript loop function, I'm confused on what you want though

Comment: sorry ... i have updated the question, im using htaccess and i want to to that via html so it will redirect after 5 seconds